# Can this math calculation be done on a single line in bash?

Tags: bash, datetime

Write a formula to convert an SQL time value to epoch time, then use that with today's date to calculate the time difference in days. I would like to do this with a single bashline command.

First, trim the SQL time number:

```
printf "%.*f\n" 0 40020.7278236459
```

= 40021

Then convert to epoch time:

```
echo "(40021 - 25569) * 86400" | bc
```

= 1248652800

The above result will now be used with the current epoch time date, which is calculated by:

```
date +%s
```

= 1509720642

So, if  1509720642 - 1248652800
= 261067842, you can divide this difference by 86400 to obtain the solution, which is the number in days:

```
261067842 / 86400
```

= 3021

Now, how do you do all of this with one bashline formula?

Comment: You can do *any* formulaic calculation in one line of `bash` if it's a call to a function, or with judicious usage of the `;` command separator :-)

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for answers to test/interview questions,
tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @user3447273, Any luck with any of the solutions provided below?

Comment: Yes, Matt's answer was a direct, single line solution that worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is heinous, but it works. You can use `expr` to evaluate an expression and wrap your commands in `$()` to execute them.

```
expr $(expr $(date +%s) - $(echo "($(printf "%.*f\n" 0 40020.7278236459) - 25569) * 86400" | bc)) / 86400
```

I would prefer to use multiple lines to express the script clearly.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it (in `bash`), by (more or less) literal translation of your algorithm:

```
result=$(( ($(date +%s) - ($(printf "%.0f\n" 40020.7278236459) - 25569) * 86400) / 86400 ))
```

and using the [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) `$((..))` for integer arithmetic and [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) `$(..)` for capturing outputs of (sub-)commands.

We can wrap it in a function:

```
conv() { echo $(( ($(date +%s) - ($(printf "%.0f\n" "$1") - 25569) * 86400) / 86400 )); }
```

and use it like:

```
$ conv 40020.7278236459
3031
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a following command line for your solution,

```
$ _SQL_TIME=40020.7278236459; echo "( $(date '+%s') - (( $(( $(echo ${_SQL_TIME} | awk '{ printf "%.f\n", $1}') - 25569 )) ) * 86400) ) / 86400" | bc
```

I hope this helps you.